# Vertex Coordinate Generation

Tags: 3d, vertex, coordinate

I have base quad mesh that has 4 points on x-z plain (-8.0f,0.0f,-8.0f),(8.0f,0.0f,-8.0f),(8.0f,0.0f,8.0f),(-8,0.0f.0f,8.0f). If I ask a user to choose arbitrary number of dimension, for example 2x2 or 64x64, Then what I need to do is to create vertex array and store those coordinates since i need to create that many quad meshes. I can't come up with clean solution of solving that problem. I also need to use that vertices to create quads, so it would be important the vertices are created in order to be used to create quad meshes later

So this is a function that I'm working on it

void initializeMesh(float originX, float originZ, float xWidth, float zWidth)
{
    // originX and Z moves along the edges of boundary, scanning fashion

}

Does it seem like a decent idea? x and z width are calculated based on user input dimension (16.0f / dimX and 16.0f / dimY) and I would need to figure out when to stop traversing.

Comment: Show your "unclear" solution or say what exactly is your problem.  Ppl here will help you find solution. But they will not find it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I just started working on a function and I just want I'm heading right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If dimension is power of two(like you're example 2x2, 64x64) you can do it with loop. Each iteration divide each edge(vertical or horizontal space between neighboring vertices) in half. New vertices positions will be arithmetical mean of neighboring vertices. Repeat it until desired dimension reached. I recommend list us data structure because you will need to inject new nodes(vertices) in it and it will be easer and faster with list than array.

It will not mess-up vertex order and you can extend it to support vertex attributes (like texture coordinates) they also will be arithmetical mean.